# Update row order by date

Tags: mysql

I've asked this question in the morning, but did not get any answer for this. So I delete previous one, and ask this again cause I am getting stuck for a long while. Hope you guys can help me.

I have a table named `overtime` like following:

```
| total | remain |              t_date |
|-------|--------|---------------------|
|     3 |      0 | 2016-01-01 12:20:00 |
|     4 |      0 | 2016-02-01 13:10:00 |
|     2 |      0 | 2016-03-01 14:40:00 |
|     3 |      0 | 2016-04-01 10:20:00 |
|     5 |      2 | 2016-05-01 17:20:00 |
```

I want to update column remain `order by t_date desc`, also I have an input parameter, assume it is $h = 9, the expected result is:

```
| total | remain |              t_date |
|-------|--------|---------------------|
|     5 |      5 | 2016-05-01 17:20:00 | -- remain will be updated to 5 cause total = 5, then $h(6) = $h(9) - (total(5) - remain(2)) 
|     3 |      3 | 2016-04-01 10:20:00 | -- remain will be updated to 3 cause total = 3, then $h(3) = $h(6) - (total(3) - remain(0)) 
|     2 |      2 | 2016-03-01 14:40:00 | -- remain will be updated to 2 cause total = 2, then $h(1) = $h(3) - (total(2) - remain(0))
|     4 |      1 | 2016-02-01 13:10:00 | -- remain will be updated to 1 cause $h only has 1, then $h will be 0
|     3 |      0 | 2016-01-01 12:20:00 | -- cause $h = 0, this row has no need to be updated
```

***Edited:***
The sample data is like above, what I want to do is update column `remain`, and `remain`'value bases on total and an input parameter(just assume it is 9):

- update order is `order by t_date desc`. For example, I must update `2016-05-01 17:20:00` row first, then `2016-04-01 10:20:00`, then `2016-03-01 14:40:00` and so on...
- Parameter is 9, it will be allocated to every row, and `remain` should be updated to `total`'s value. For example, the first row `2016-05-01 17:20:00`, `total` = 5 and `remain` = 2, so `remain` will be updated to 5, and parameter will minus `total` - `remain`, it will be 6 and do the next row's allocation, till row `2016-02-01 13:10:00`, the paramter is 1, so this row's `remain` only needs to updated to 1. And another row will have no need to updated.

[**Here is SQLFiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59d9d4).
If there is any unclear point for question, please leave a comment, I can explain that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking you again : `remain will be updated to 5 cause total = 5, then $h(6) = $h(9) - (total(5) - remain(2))`. Could you be more elaborate on this?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear to me.  Please clarify the logic used for making the updates.  The Fiddle is empty.

Comment: Why does the final *remain* column not have 1 in the 3rd row? There is a total of 2 available, and *h* is large enough, so should there not be 2 taken from the previous 3 (i.e. value of *remain* in 2nd row)?

Comment: @1000111 Check my edited quetion.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Check my edited quetion.

Comment: @trincot Check my edited quetion.

Comment: So, do you want `UPDATE/SELECT` query?

Comment: Cause when to third row, the paramter is 3 and `total` = 2, so remain will get `total`'s value, and the paramter will remain 1 to update to forth row. @trincot

Comment: @1000111 `Update` query.

Comment: @All, Notice that `update` has `order by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SELECT QUERY:**

```
    SELECT 
    *,
    IF(
        (IF(@h <= 0,0,IF(@h >= total,total, @h)) + remain) <= total, 
        (IF(@h <= 0,0,IF(@h >= total,total, @h)) + remain), 
        (IF(@h <= 0,0,IF(@h >=  total,total, @h)))
      ) allocated,
    @h := @h - (total - remain)
    FROM overtime
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @h := 9) var
    ORDER BY t_date DESC
```

<kbd>[**Demo of SELECT**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/214215e/2/0)</kbd>

**UPDATE QUERY:**

```
UPDATE 
overtime OT 
INNER JOIN 

(
        SELECT 
        *,
        IF(
          (IF(@h <= 0,0,IF(@h >= total,total, @h)) + remain) <= total, 
          (IF(@h <= 0,0,IF(@h >= total,total, @h)) + remain), 
          (IF(@h <= 0,0,IF(@h >=  total,total, @h)))
         ) allocated,
    @h := @h - (total - remain)
    FROM overtime
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @h := 9) var
    ORDER BY t_date DESC
) AS t
ON OT.t_date = t.t_date
SET OT.remain = t.allocated;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/656fee/1/0)</kbd>

*Demo shows the table data sorted by descending order of date after being updated by the above `update` query.*

**More:**

[**See Demo for h=2**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/694fd7/1/0)

Comment: Thanks. This is also almost there, but if @h = 2, I want remain to be 4(`total` + @h), this will get me 2.

Comment: Again obscure requirement. Could you please explain why?

Comment: Sorry for my trouble, this is more like a rollback operation, in fact, I've get this 9 from `remain` and `order by t_date asc` ,  then for some reason, I'd like return this 9 to `remain`, so if what I get is 2, it means from `2016-05-01 17:20:00`, and now it remains 2, so when return to this row, it will sum them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sub-query that makes the calculations using a variable *@h*:

```
update   overtime 
join     (select   t_date,
                   least(@h,total) 
                      + if(least(@h,total) + remain <= total, remain, 0)  new_remain,
                   @h := greatest(0, @h - (total - remain)) h
          from     overtime,
                   (select @h := 9) init
          order by t_date desc
         ) as calc
      on overtime.t_date = calc.t_date   
set      overtime.remain := calc.new_remain;
```

See this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d402/1)

Comment: Thanks. This is almost there, but if @h = 2, I want `remain` to be 4(`total` + @h), this will get me 2.

Comment: OK, I see in my absence an answer was already accepted. Still I have updated mine, as I think it is more readable (shorter formula).

Answer (score 1):

You must use a sub query to do this, like following:

```
update overtime t1
join (
  select overtime.*,
  total - remain, IF(@h > (total - remain), total, @h + remain) as h,
  @h := IF(@h > (total - remain), @h - (total - remain), 0)
  from overtime
  cross join (
      select @h := 9
  ) t
  order by t_date desc
) t2 on t1.t_date = t2.t_date
set t1.remain = t2.h;
```

### Demo Here